# Query to join two tables with like operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two table which has data as below

Table1

```
+-----+-------+-------------------------+
| ID  | value |          Test           |
+-----+-------+-------------------------+
| 200 |  2456 | yyy xxcv zuio uio tzrue |
| 201 |  2905 | xxx tttt ssrt uio uioe  |
| 203 | 34567 | zzz iii ool uiol werts  |
| 204 |  2356 | xxx tttt ssrt uio wertz |
| 205 |  3478 | io ser xcv erto klop    |
| 206 |  4567 | xxx tttt ssrt uio poiu  |
| 207 |   234 | zzz iii ool uiol wert   |
+-----+-------+-------------------------+
```

I would like to create where clause to get rows with like operator. 
for ex.

```
select *
from Table1
where test like '%xxcv zuio%' Or Like '%iii ool%' OR '%xcv erto%' OR '%ssrt uio%' OR '%uio uioe%'
```

But my problem is that there are more than 15-20 different parameter in where clause, it can also increase latter.

So I have decided to create a new table in database lets called it Table2 with parameter as shown below.

Table2

```
+----+-----------+
| ID | Parameter |
+----+-----------+
| 20 | xxcv zuio |
| 21 | iii ool   |
| 22 | xcv erto  |
| 23 | ssrt uio  |
| 24 | uio uioe  |
+----+-----------+
```

My question is how can I join this table to give the same result like above query.

I am still learning joins so any advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from Table1 t1
where exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.test like concat('%', t2.parameter, '%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using a join is helping in this scenario, and this kind of text searching is not a strong point for SQL Server. Consider building an elasticsearch index or using another system that supports text searching as a primary use case (SQL Server does support full text search if that feature is enabled, but I've always been warned away from it, so don't have experience with it.)

If staying within TSQL is desirable for your particular situation, then I would use the awkward "OR LIKE" syntax. What it lacks in elegance it makes up for in readability.